# Microsoft.Exchange.Data.MultiValuedProperty documentation anywhere?

Tags: .net, powershell

Exchange (2016 in my very case) powershell cmdlets return data using this type but I can not find any up-to-date documentation, only deprecated ones like [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/exchange-server-api/aa580915(v=exchg.150)) or [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa567082(v=exchg.140)).

do you know of any up-to-date documentation on this type, or information on how it compares to System.Collections.Generic.List or System.Collections.ArrayList?

Comment: The documentation for these core DTO types is unlikely to have changed between Exchange 2010 and 2016. Are you running into a specific issue where the (old) documentation disagrees with the (new) behavior you're seeing? If so, please share code with which you can reproduce the issue :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen no specific issue, just the pink banner at the pages top saying ```We're no longer updating this content regularly. Check the Microsoft Product Lifecycle for information about how this product, service, technology, or API is supported.``` and the URL starting with ```https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/...```

Comment: Looks like there is no updated documentation. The current [Exchange Input/Output types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/management/exchange-management-shell-cmdlet-input-and-output-types) still refers to the outdated page that you referenced already (the v150 link).